# How Convert DataSet to List<ArrayList>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I have a dataset ds and a List of ArrayList newpath i want to add(assign) ds to newpath
how is that possible.

```
public List<ArrayList> newpath
    {
        set { ViewState["newpath"] = value; }
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["newpath"] == null)
                return new List<ArrayList>();
            else
                return (List<ArrayList>)ViewState["newpath"];
        }
    }
```

i am trying with

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in Ftb.Rows)//Ftb is datatable
 {
    newpath.Add(dataRow);//newpath is List<ArrayList>
 }
```

and

```
foreach (DataRow dRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
   newpath.Add(dRow);
 }
```

if i am doing like above way then i am getting the error
"The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(System.Collections.ArrayList)' has some invalid arguments"

Please help me if in someway.. how to do that

Comment: Just as you can't add a string to a list of ints, you can't add a datarow to a list of arraylists, it is a datarow not an arraylist. Make a new arraylist and then add the data from the row to the arraylist then add that to the list of arraylists.

Comment: Is it just me, or does a `List<ArrayList>` just smell wrong? Ditto for a `List` of anything in a ViewState?

Comment: The biggest question is, what do you want to do next with this `List<ArrayList>`? Are you sure you really need a `List<ArrayList>`?

Comment: Don't store data in the viewstate like this, viewstate is to maintain state e.g. the selected value of a control.  It is not a cache and will probably make things slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want each item in `newpath` to contain the column values of each row?
If so, have such code instead:

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in Ftb.Rows)//Ftb is datatable
{
    ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
    foreach (object value in dataRow.ItemArray)
        values.Add(value);
    newpath.Add(values);
}
```

Comment: why not filling it by constructor `ArrayList values = new ArrayList(dataRow.ItemArray)`?

Comment: but in newpath values is not getting added

Comment: You should add curly braces to the foreach block even if it contains only one line. It is better for readability and maintanance.

Comment: @Oliver `object[]` does not implement `ICollection` so as far as I know, it won't compile.

Comment: Rocky - as you accepted the answer I assume it's working fine?

Comment: @elsni it's personal "taste", to me having three lines just for one "real" line is a waste and less readable.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted it looks as if your `newpath` variable is a list of ArrayLists. So when you try to add `dRow` which is `DataRow` you're getting an error as it's not an `ArrayList`.

If you want to add DataRows I think `newpath` should be a list of `DataRow`. If you wanted to populate the ArrayList with data from the DataRow you'd need something like this -

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in Ftb.Rows)//Ftb is datatable
 {
      ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
      myAL.Add(dataRow["your_column_name"]);
      //add fields from DataRow to array list using your required logic
      newpath.Add(myAL);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change newpath from

```
List<ArrayList>
```

to

```
List<DataRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified @Shadow Wizard code and now its working fine

```
List<ArrayList> newval = new List<ArrayList>();
    foreach (DataRow dRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
      {
        ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
        foreach (object value in dRow.ItemArray)
            values.Add(value);
            newval.Add(values);
      }
 newpath = newval;
```